# Ajustar altura del mapa Javascript al DIV completo

Tags: javascript, css, css3

El siguiente mapa javascript (leaflet) se ajusta al ancho, pero no al alto del div. Tengo una altura de 850px, pero la idea es ajustar verticalmente también y no tener un height fijo. No se si me he explicado bien. Gracias.

Añadiendo height: 100%; en vez de height: 850px; el plano leaflet desaparece. Se queda blanco.

Código:

```
<style>
html, body {
  width: 100%;
}
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 850px;
}
</style>

<div id='map'>

</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Lo que yo uso para dar ajuste a los mapas es con la propiedad `padding-bottom`, lo que entiendo de esta propiedad es que establece un relleno inferior en el contenedor.

```
.map{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    top: 0%;
    bottom: 0%;
    padding-bottom: 60%;
}
```

Lo uso en un mapa con leaflet para que se haga responsivo, lo he usado con o sin bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Si el contenedor padre no tiene una altura especificada no va a funcionar asignar altura relativa (%) a `#map`

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  background-color:yellow;
}
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div id='map'>
  Esto no se adapta
</div>
```

Basta con definir la altura del contenedor padre para que el hijo se adapte:

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color:yellow;
}
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div id='map'>
  Este sí se adapta
</div>
```

Si quieres eliminar los márgenes que se ven y evitar desborde por márgenes internos (padding) y externos (margin) que definas posteriormente, solo necesitas un reset CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```